# Packing images for SikuliX in Maven

Tags: java, maven, sikuli

I'm writing an application that utilizes SikuliX, and I'm having problems generating a jar from my code.

I have the images used for my code stored in `src/main/resources`, and I'm building the jar using this code in my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.dustinroepsch.leadtimetool.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I open the created JAR with 7-zip, I can see that my images are being added to the root of the jar. I think that's what I want, but I'm not sure.

I'm referencing the images in my my code via

```
Screen s = new Screen();
ImagePath.add("src/main/resources");
s.hover("1462980188453.png");
```

And when I launch my code through the Netbeans "play" button it runs great.

However, in when I run the jar with dependencies from the command line, I get the error

```
FindFailed: Region: doFind: Image not loadable: 1462980188453.png
```

The images are packed in the jar, and the jar has the sikuli dependencies in side of it. Is there a imagepath for me to add, such that my executable jar will find the images correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a good solution.

Maven automatically packs everything in your resources directory into the root of the jar.

What you should do is make a folder in your resources directory called "images" (or anything), and place your folder inside of it.

Then you can use `ImagePath.add("com.yourcompany.yourpackage.AnyClass/images");`

Things will then work as intended